# A cross table in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this one:

```
   v1   v2  wght
1  3    5   0.2
2  2    8   0.5
3  3    5   0.6
................
```

So I want to produce some descriptive statistics for multiple variables, a cross table more precisely. The values of v1 and v2 are all integers between 1 and 10 and wght is a weight variable. The desired result should be a data frame like this one for example:

```
        v2_1 ... v2_5 ... v2_8 ...   v2_10
v1_1
v1_2                       0.5
v1_3         0.8=0.2+0.6
...
v1_10
```

where in each cell you have the number of people who are v2_i amongst those who have v1_j for i and j in [1:10]. These data should be weighted by wght.
I tried using Crosstable but the results are impossible to be used afterwards because I need a data frame. Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear what you want to fill in the cross table.  Is it the sum of the wght variable for the combination of `v1`, `v2` or something else?  Perhaps `xtabs(wght~v1+v2, df1)`

Comment: Take this example: first line v1=5, v2=10, wght=0,2; second line v1=7, v2=9, wght=0,5. So in my crossed table I should have 0,2 in the cell (v1_5,v2_10) and 0,5 in (v1_7, v2_9).

Comment: Please do update in your post so that other may also notice your update

Comment: Did you try @akrun's first comment, because that seems to do what you're asking for.

Comment: @akrun I got the cross table of the two variables but it is however not weighted. I didn't understand the purpose of value.var because whatever I put in value.var I got the same table afterwards.

Comment: @rado I don't understand it is not weighted.  You are summing the 'wght` for the same combination of `v1` and `v2`, which is exactly what `xtabs` or `dcast` does.

Comment: @akrun my mistake. Thanks a lot ;) Last question : how do I get the data frame from xtabs ? as.data.frame (xtabs(wght~v1+v2, df1)) gives me a data frame with 121 lines and not a table 11x11

Comment: Try `as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(wght~v1+v2, df1))`

Comment: It works perfectly, 10x a lot ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
library(reshape2)
df1[1:2] <- lapply(df1[1:2], function(x) factor(x, levels=1:10))
res1 <- as.data.frame(acast(df1, v1 ~v2 , value.var='wght',
                         fill=0, drop=FALSE, sum))
```

Or

```
as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(wght~v1+v2, df1))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(v1= sample(1:10, 20, replace=TRUE), 
      v2= sample(1:10, 20, replace=TRUE), wght=rnorm(20))
```